# Max character length for Read command (input)

Tags: bash, shell-script, read

I have bash script that have input commands.

```
echo "Enter the id: " 
read id
```

I'd like to know if there's a way I can limit the character can I input in the for `id`. I mean example he can only enter 5 characters for `id`.

is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So with `bash` there are (at least) two options.

The first is `read -n 5`.  This may sound like it meets your needs.  From the man page

```
-n nchars
       read  returns after reading nchars characters rather than
       waiting for a complete line of input, but honor a  delim-
       iter  if fewer than nchars characters are read before the
       delimiter.
```

BUT there's a gotcha here.  If the user types `abcde` then the `read` completes *without* them needing to press RETURN.  This limits the results to 5 characters, but may not be a good user experience.  People are *used* to pressing RETURN.

The second method is just to test the length of the input and complain if it's too long.  We use the fact that `${#id}` is the length of the string.

This results in a pretty standard loop.

```
ok=0

while [ $ok = 0 ]
do
  echo "Enter the id: " 
  read id
  if [ ${#id} -gt 5 ]
  then
    echo Too long - 5 characters max
  else
    ok=1
  fi
done
```

If you want it to be *exactly* 5 characters then you can change the `if` test from `-gt` to `-eq`.

Comment: Note that the `read -d 5` counts the characters (not bytes, and if there are bytes not forming valid characters, you may get unexpected results) **before** the IFS trimming and **after** backslash processing. For insance, if you enter `<space><space>abcd`, it will store `abc` in `$id`, and if you enter `\a\b\c\d\e`, it will store `abcde` in `$id`. To avoid IFS trimming and backslash processing, use `IFS= read -rn 5 id`

Comment: Note that `zsh` has `read -k n` to read n characters (long before `bash`), but it's more like `ksh93`'s `read -N` in that it will not stop at newline. Like for bash's `read -n` or ksh's `read -n/N`, if the input is coming from a terminal, the terminal is put out of the canonical mode, so bytes are sent as soon as they are entered, which also means things like backspace or ctrl-u won't work as usual.